# Setting Python Interpreter in Eclipse (Mac)

Tags: python, eclipse, macos

How do I direct Eclipse to the Python interpreter on my Mac?

I've looked in Library which contains the directory 'Python' then '2.3' and '2.5', however they contain nothing except 'Site-packages' - Which is weird considering I can go into the terminal and type `python`. I then installed the latest 2.6 version with package manager and still can't find it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alias to the python interpreter was likely installed into `/usr/local/bin`.  So, to invoke python2.6, type `/usr/local/bin/python2.6` or, most likely, just `python2.6`.  If you want python to invoke python2.6, try rearranging your `$PATH` so that `/usr/local/bin` precedes `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 7):

Running $which python should help locate your Python installation.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this for my Mac and it was located in

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

The way I found it is as follows:

(1) I tried entering the following to see if I could find where Python was located

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

This had the location of a custom install of Python that came from another program I downloaded, but I wanted the native Python.

(2) I wanted to see every folder in the path so I could look for python

```
echo $PATH
```

This returned the following:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

(2b) I CDed into every one of these locations and searched for python in each one.

```
cd /usr/bin/
ls | grep "python"
```

And I eventually found Python.

In Eclipse, with PyDev, if you (1) click Preferences (2) PyDev (3) Interpreter - Python, you can add the interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed python on mac, follow belows steps (on eclipse neon)

1. Click on Preferences
2. Search for python
3. Below screen will appear

   [image]
4. Click Choose from list 
   [image]
5. It will show up all the python installed and select one for you

Hope it helps some one. It resolve my problem.